# Rally SOAP API - Missing class RallyServiceService after importing into a .net project

Tags: c#, .net, soap, rally

I'm using a Rally trial account to do an integration proof-of-concept, so I can estimate how much would it cost to integrate our systems with Rally.

I am trying to use the Rally SOAP API with .net, following Rally documentation (/doc/webservice/dotnetsoap.jsp)
I have managed to successfully import Rally Web Services into my c# project, but then Rally documentation says I have to create an object from class RallyServiceService, and although I have a bunch of classes available, this one is not there.

Has anyone else had this problem?

I would appreciate any help.
Thanks

EDIT: (After Jérémie comment)

My code looks like this:

```
using MyProject.MyNamespace.Rally;

namespace MyProject.MyNamespace {
  public class MyClass: MyInterface {
    public void MyMethod() {
      *RallyServiceService doesn't exist here*
```

Comment: The classes are autogenerated and not visible directly in the solution explorer of Visual Studio if you use it.
But if you add the namespace of the service in your file (using ...) you can use the generated classes like RallyServiceService.

Comment: Hi Jérémie, thank you for your answer. I had already done that. I can see a bunch of Rally classes in that namespace, just not the RallyServiceService one.

Comment: What are the classes available in the new Rally namespace?
Do you have specified something before the generation?

Answer (score 2):

We actually recommend using our REST API rather than SOAP, especially for new development.  There is a nice .NET toolkit to help you get started.  Docs, code examples and more can be found here:

http://developer.rallydev.com/help/rest-api-net

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Kyle.
Is there a version of the .NET toolkit for the 3.5 Framework?
To integrate with the REST API I will have to do it in the 3.5 Framework.
Thanks

Comment: Rally's .NET REST API requires .NET 4.0/Visual Studio 2010, unfortunately there is no version for .NET 3.5.

Answer (score 1):

A resounding +1 to Kyle's recommendation to use Rally's REST API for .NET. Rally's REST API is far more robust, easier to use, and much more performant. If you're just getting started on your integration - you should definitely go with REST :)

However, if you choose to do .NET SOAP, the issue you describe usually results from having added the Rally WSDL as a ServiceReference, instead of adding it as the needed WebReference.

Here's how to add it as a Web Reference:

1. Open your project in Visual Studio
2. Right-click on Service Reference -> Add Service Reference

[image: Add Service Reference]

3. Click Advanced

[image: Advanced Button]

4. Click Add Web Reference

[image: Add Web Reference]

5. Paste in the WSDL URL and click the green arrow

[image: Add WSDL]

6. Enter Credentials

[image: Enter Credentials]

7. Click through mixed-zone security warnings

[image]

8. Name Service as desired

[image: Name Service]

9. Note presence of Web Reference in Solution Explorer

[image: Web Referecnce]

10. Observe RallyServiceService in object/method hierarchy

[image: RallyServiceService]